# Symfony 2 permissions for web folder

Tags: php, symfony

I added the lightbox and the path to the icons (forward, backward) not available on the Web (forbidden).

how to allow access to `/lightbox/images`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony's default `.htaccess` thinks `/lightbox/images` is actual route. You have to add an exception:

```
# allow access to lightbox
RewriteRule ^lightbox.* - [QSA,L]
```

However, why don't you add `lightbox` folder to `web/`?

Comment: I put to web folder. full path project/web/lightbox. I add your rewrite rule, but nothing :(. Other folder as images, css, js, foto work correctly.

Comment: Now I'm bit confused. What exactly doesn't work? Reading from folder or writing to it?

Comment: I get 403 error when request lightbox/images. lightbox folder full path is project/web/lightbox/images

Comment: But that should be alright as files should be readable. If you want to browse directory, just create .htaccess with Allow from all in it.